# When I run the given code I get A B A as output. I don't understand why it prints A again

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

Tha code mentioned below returns 
A
B
A
as output but I didnt understand the logic why A has been printed again after B.

```
class A1 {
    public A1() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A1 implements Serializable {
    public B() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        B b = new B();      // Object of class B
        ObjectOutputStream objout=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("t.txt"));
        objout.writeObject(b);

        ObjectInputStream objin=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("t.txt"));
        objin.readObject();
    }

}
```

Comment: Check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317063/why-is-the-first-constructor-called-after-deserialization-and-no-others

Answer (score 4):

This explains it, the ctor of B is not called again because it's serializable.

> Reading an object is analogous to running the constructors of a new object. Memory is allocated for the object and initialized to zero (NULL). No-arg constructors are invoked for the non-serializable classes.

`A B` is printed when you call `new B()`, which first calls the ctor of A and then B.
Then `objin.readObject()` calls only the ctor of A and prints the second `A`.

Comment: Thanks!. I verified and understood the logic.

Answer (score 1):

When you extend any class, it will invoke constructor of `super class` while creating object of `subclass`.

Just example: `object B` created then it will first invoke constructor of **A1** first.
and `objin.readObject()` calls only constructor of A.

**Edit:**

> The no-arg contructor of every non-serializable superclass will run when an object is deserialized. However, the deserialized objects? constructor does not run when it is deserialized.

Comment: does not answer the question

Comment: @upog Yes, It was not answer as OP expected. I edited answer. It might help to OP.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for `A` is called during deserialization because `A` does not implement `Serializable`. This answer explains it well:

[Java: Why doesn't deserialization invoke constructor & what's the best workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151711/java-why-doesnt-deserialization-invoke-constructor-whats-the-best-workaroun)

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are invoked from base class to derived classes..

So,for `B b = new B();` Constructors would be invoked in the order A->B Hence printing `A B`

---

Now for `objin.readObject();`

Only A's constructor would be invoked not B's constructor.This is because

- For serializable objects, the no-arg constructor for the first **non-serializable** supertype (i.e `A1`) is run. *Since `A1`, doesn't implement Serializable,it's construtor would be invoked*
- Constructors are **not** executed for `serializable` classes(i.e `B`) during deserialization. *Hence B's constructor is not invoked the second time*

Hence the output, `A B A`

This is mentioned in [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html)

Answer (score 0):

Java docs of [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) says ,

> Reading an object is analogous to running the constructors of a new
>   object. Memory is allocated for the object and initialized to zero
>   (NULL). **No-arg constructors are invoked for the non-serializable
>   classes and then the fields of the serializable classes are restored**
>   from the stream starting with the serializable class closest to
>   java.lang.object and finishing with the object's most specific class.

Therefore while creating class B instance,

```
B b = new B();  // prints A B
```

it prints A ,B and

while deserializing ,

```
objin.readObject();  // prints A as per docs
```

it prints A because class A is non-serializable and docs says No-arg constructors are invoked for the non-serializable classes .

So together you get output as `A B A`